# html. растянуть видео на всю страницу

Tags: css, html5

всем привет. я новичок в html. хочу растянуть видео на всю страницу (желательно еще и динамически - чтоб на телефонах_планшетах все тоже работало) - и в div пихал, и display: flex; justify-content: center; прописывал, но вот как растянуть конкретно на весь экран - не знаю. в гугле точного ответа тоже не нашел. прошу помощи у знатоков. если не можете\не хотите отвечать - прошу хотя бы дать ссылки на ресурсы, где об этом можно почитать\посмотреть. а еще autoplay Не работает, что очень печально.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#video-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

#video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="video-container">
    <video id="video" controls loop 
      poster="https://www.film.ru/sites/default/files/movies/posters/50483019-2577104.jpeg">
      <source src="https://www.film.ru/sites/default/files/trailers/50483019/Miraculous-clip_2.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```